# Is it possible to only call Viewport Meta tag at 768px and below?

Tags: android, ipad, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

**The basic question:**

Is there away I can set the viewport meta tag to only come into effect at 768px and below?

**Reason:**

I've built a responsive e-commerce site using standard @media browser sizes:

Over 1200px
1025px to 1199px
980px to 1024px
768px to 979px

Due to the complexity of the site it's not viable, time or layout wise, for me to use @media queries to make the site usable for mobile browsers so I'd like to use the viewport meta tag to force all small mobile browsers to display the 768px to 979px layout.

To do this I can easily use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768px; />
```

The only problem with that is that it over-rides the 980px to 1024px @media queries designed for iPad landscape, and forces iPad Landscape to display the smaller layout I designed for iPad Portrait, i.e. the 768px to 979px layout.

The answer to my prayers would be if I could set the viewport meta tag to only come into effect at 768px and below - is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**BOOM! FIXED!**

Right, this was a miserable waste of 6 hours but it's done and working now, hope this helps someone!

First of all, I included a pretty standard Viewport Meta Tag in my functions.php file:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.2, user-scalable=yes" />
```

I then used jQuery Mobile in my header.php to look at the browser width and to change the Viewport size to 768px IF the browser width was below 700px:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="">

    <script>
        if($.mobile.media("screen and (max-device-width: 700px)")) {
            // Change viewport for smaller devices
            $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=768px');
        }
    </script>
```

This works great - it keeps my nice, responsive layouts for iPad Landscape and Portrait and gives a nice viewport size for mobiles. Lovely